# Output a list of tuples of strings and a single integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My code seems to be correct, but my output is a bit different from the expected output.

My code returns:

```
amino_acids('AUGUCGGCACAUUUAUGCUCCUAAUCC') == (['Met', 'Ser', 'Ala', 'His', 'Leu', 'Cys', 'Ser'], 6)
```

This is the expected output:

```
amino_acids('AUGUCGGCACAUUUAUGCUCCUAAUCC') == [('Met', 'Ser', 'Ala', 'His', 'Leu', 'Cys', 'Ser'), 6]
```

I tried to return [] and I also tried change some of the brackets used when coding but the results doesn't get to the expected output. Here is my code:

```py
### START FUNCTION 
def amino_acids(mrna):
    codon_dict = {'CUU': 'Leu', 'UAG': '---', 'ACA': 'Thr', 'AAA': 'Lys', 'AUC': 'Ile',
        'AAC': 'Asn', 'AUA': 'Ile', 'AGG': 'Arg', 'CCU': 'Pro', 'ACU': 'Thr',
        'AGC': 'Ser', 'AAG': 'Lys', 'AGA': 'Arg', 'CAU': 'His', 'AAU': 'Asn',
        'AUU': 'Ile', 'CUG': 'Leu', 'CUA': 'Leu', 'CUC': 'Leu', 'CAC': 'His',
        'UGG': 'Trp', 'CAA': 'Gln', 'AGU': 'Ser', 'CCA': 'Pro', 'CCG': 'Pro',
        'CCC': 'Pro', 'UAU': 'Tyr', 'GGU': 'Gly', 'UGU': 'Cys', 'CGA': 'Arg',
        'CAG': 'Gln', 'UCU': 'Ser', 'GAU': 'Asp', 'CGG': 'Arg', 'UUU': 'Phe',
        'UGC': 'Cys', 'GGG': 'Gly', 'UGA': '---', 'GGA': 'Gly', 'UAA': '---',
        'ACG': 'Thr', 'UAC': 'Tyr', 'UUC': 'Phe', 'UCG': 'Ser', 'UUA': 'Leu',
        'UUG': 'Leu', 'UCC': 'Ser', 'ACC': 'Thr', 'UCA': 'Ser', 'GCA': 'Ala',
        'GUA': 'Val', 'GCC': 'Ala', 'GUC': 'Val', 'GGC': 'Gly', 'GCG': 'Ala',
        'GUG': 'Val', 'GAG': 'Glu', 'GUU': 'Val', 'GCU': 'Ala', 'GAC': 'Asp',
        'CGU': 'Arg', 'GAA': 'Glu', 'AUG': 'Met', 'CGC': 'Arg'}
    
    amino_acid_list = []
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(mrna):
        codon = mrna[i:i + 3]
        if codon == 'UAG' or codon == 'UGA' or codon == 'UAA':
            break
        if codon in codon_dict:
            amino_acid_list.append(codon_dict[codon])
        i += 3
    
    num_distinct_amino_acids = len(set(amino_acid_list))
    return amino_acid_list, num_distinct_amino_acids
### END FUNCTION
```

Comment: You can do `return [tuple(amino_acid_list), num_distinct_amino_acids]`

Comment: `return [amino_acid_list, num_distinct_amino_acids]`

Comment: I could not see a difference between the actual and the expected output yet. Could you clarify where the difference is? oh, now I see: list of tuples vs. tuple of lists.

Comment: Your code returns a *tuple*, explicitly, here: `return amino_acid_list, num_distinct_amino_acids`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```py
return amino_acid_list, num_distinct_amino_acids
```

to

```py
return [tuple(amino_acid_list), num_distinct_amino_acids]
```

When you just use comma by itself it creates a tuple, not a list; you need to wrap it in `[]` to get a list. And since `amino_acid_list` is a list, you need to call `tuple()` to convert it to a tuple.